# Monotouch AMDeviceInstallApplication returned: 0xe8008018

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I have recently installed iOS 6 beta on my device and updated to the latest mono develop release. Since this, I now get the following error when trying to deploy to my device, "Installation failed: AMDeviceInstallApplication returned: 0xe8008018" - Could not upload to the device.

I have tried other projects and get the same error. As far as I'm aware, there is no code signing problems - all appears fine in the log. It worked fine before I installed IOS6. I don't have another device with iOS 5 to test.

Any ideas as to why I am getting this error?

Thank you.

Comment: You cannot ask this question here.  It is a violation of the NDA you agreed to with your account.  You cannot discuss this outside of the developer forums until iOS 6 is publicly released.

Comment: I'm not sure that's true, he's not really discussing the beta but problems with MonoTouch.  I know Xamarin is working on getting the betas to work with MonoDevelop/MonoTouch, and they haven't released an update mentioning it.  Maybe they can let us know how it's coming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using any non-standard names for the Xcode executables, check Xamarin's blog post on how to fix it:

http://blog.xamarin.com/2012/06/15/xcode-4-5-ios-6-and-mountain-lion/

Or even better, contact support@xamarin.com

Comment: Thanks. Looks like the error is because I have iOS 6 installed. Great blog entry from zamarin.

Answer (score 1):

I get this message once a year when my developer certificate expires on my build machine. 
Yep my Macbook Pro is from 2010.
So just look in the iOS Developer console under Certificates. If it says you do not have one then you need to go through the process to create a new one.  I also look in KeyChain to see if the one in there has a red X indicating it to be expired.
I hope this helps.